# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined

Tags: javascript, exception, sapui5, instantiation

Currently I am working on an Upgradation project; I am facing the Below **Exception** when I instantiate the Custom **Router Class** from the **Component.js**; the Application specific configurations are configured in separate **manifest.json** file. The issue is that I couldn't able to read the manifest.json configs from Component.js.

I have created SAP Ui5 applications from Scratch in which I have implemented thru SAP's Best Methodologies and they were all working perfectly, I have even cross checked the Manifest files of a working Ui5 Application, Everything is perfect, but still I am unable to spot the issue and I am getting the below Exception.

Exception/Error:

```
UIComponent.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined
    at f.init (Component.js:21)
    at f.constructor (sap-ui-core.js:135)
    at f.constructor (sap-ui-core.js:141)
    at f.constructor (UIComponent.js:6)
    at new f (sap-ui-core.js:135)
    at Object.sap.ui.component (sap-ui-core.js:141)
    at F.a.onBeforeRendering (ComponentContainer.js:6)
    at F.a._callEventHandles (sap-ui-core.js:147)
    at F.a._handleEvent (sap-ui-core.js:147)
    at t (sap-ui-core.js:147)
```

Component.js [Please note: Below I have shared only init method ]

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "xxxx/app/xxxxx/MyRouter"
], function (UIComponent , MyRouter ) {

    return  UIComponent.extend("xxxx.app.xxxxxx.Component", {

        metadata: {
            manifest: "json"
        },

    init : function() {
        debugger; // IMDK901184 
        UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

        // I am getting the exception once the below line is executed.
        this.getRouter().initialize();  

    }
}
    });
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "_version": "1.12.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "xxxxx.app.xxxxx",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/messageBundle.properties",
        "title": "xxxx",
        "description": "xxxx",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "dataSources": {
            "mainService": {
                "uri": "xxxx.app.xxxxxx.AppScripts.config.baseURL",
                "type": "OData",
                "settings": {
                    "odataVersion": "2.0"
                }
            }
        }
    },
        "sap.ui": {
            "technology": "UI5",
            "deviceTypes": {
                "desktop": true,
                "tablet": true,
                "phone": true
            },
            "supportedThemes": [
                "sap_bluecrystal"
                ]
        },
        "sap.ui5": {

            "rootView": {
                  "viewName": "xxxxx.app.xxxxxx.POSView.App",
                  "type": "XML",
                  "async": true,
                  "id": "idAppControl"
              } ,
             "dependencies": {
                "minUI5Version": "1.30",
                "libs": {
                    "sap.m": {} ,
                    "sap.ui.core": {},
                    "sap.ui.layout": {}
                }
            },
            "models": {
                "i18n": {
                    "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                    "settings": {
                        "bundleName": "xxxx.app.xxxxxx.i18n.messageBundle"
                    }
                },
                "oMainModel": {
                    "dataSource": "mainService",
                    "settings": {
                        "useBatch": false
                    }
                }
            } ,

            "routing" : {
                "config" : {
                "routerClass" : "xxxxxx.app.xxxxxx.MyRouter", 
                "viewType" : "XML",
                "viewPath" : "xxxxxx.app.xxxxxx.POSView",
                "controlId": "idAppControl",
                "targetAggregation" : "detailPages",
                "clearTarget" : "false"
            } ,

            "routes" : [
                {

                ]
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Check the response of `this.getRouter()`

Comment: this.getRouter() is
undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess 'coz of the current installed SAP Ui5 Version is 1.26 and so the new type of declaring Manifest.json doesn't support here.

Refactored back to the Metadata section in component.js

Comment: Upgrading the UI5 lib to the [latest appropriate version](https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html) asap should be one of the highest priorities in your organization. 1.26 is an ancient release with several security issues and missed perf optimization opportunities.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to implement the getRouter() method something like :

```
init : function() { 
..

..
}    
getRouter : function () {
    return sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

But I have gave the Router class details in routing->Config section in Manifest file. So accordingly, Manifest will get initialized once the component is initialized and hence I can access the configurations from Component. But I couldn't do that!